# How to send email from the command line under linux and include the SMTP server name?

Tags: email, smtp, debian

I am looking for a single line email notification solution for linux, but one that would not assume that the machine mail agent was already configured properly.

I want to specify the SMTP server from the command.

Preferably, the solution should run on Debian without having to install new tools.